# Java Redefined Methods

Tags: java

I was unable to get a clarity on redefined methods in Java.
Below are the 2 examples I tried executing in Eclipse..

Example 1:

```
public class MyFirstJavaClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         
       Bar f = new Bar();
       f.instanceMethod();
       f.classMethod();
    }
}


class Foo {
    public static void classMethod() 
    {

        System.out.println("classMethod() in Foo");
    }

    public void instanceMethod() 
     {
        System.out.println ("instanceMethod() in Foo");
     }
        }

 class Bar extends Foo {
    public static void classMethod()  
    {
        System.out.println ("classMethod() in Bar");
    }

    public void instanceMethod() {
        System.out.println ("instanceMethod() in Bar");
    }
           
}
```

**Output of Example 1:**

> instanceMethod() in Bar
>
> classMethod() in Bar

Example 2:

```
class Dog extends Animal {

    static void dostuff() { // it's a redefinition,// not an override
        System.out.print("dddd ");
   }
    
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
      Dog obj = new Dog();
      obj.doStuff();
   }
}


class Animal {
    static void doStuff() {
       System.out.print("aaaa ");
   }
}
```

**Output of Example 2:**

> aaaa

I am not able conceptually understand the output of example 2.
In Example 2 , even if I replace the the statement `Dog obj = new Dog();`
with `Animal obj = new Animal` , the output is still the same i.e. aaaa

Why the output of example 2 when the statement is `Dog obj = new Dog();` is aaaa.
I was guessing output as dddd , but I was wrong.

It would be great of someone could throw light on this.
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Isn't your compiler giving you an error for the f.classMethod(); in example1 ?

Comment: @niilzon It's not an error, it's just bad style (and misleading) to call static methods through instances.

Comment: Hi nilizon, the program compiles fine..no errors

Comment: Can you indent your code properly please?

Comment: Thanks Berger for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `Dog`, the method name is `dostuff`, while in class `Animal`, it is called `doStuff`, which means they are different methods.

Comment: Hi Nadir ....thanks a lot ...I just missed that ...Thanks a ton for pointing out the my mistake...from the morning i was staring at the code but was not able to catch the error.... :)  Thanks

Comment: @BlueStar  use IDE to avoid that